# Problems with my js/jquery code for application frames

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My problem is that I have loaded up to application frame in js via the funtion i created called createFrame(). The fullScreen functionality isn't working properly ass it goes fullScreen nicely but if I move the application frame around the desktop it will not work properly even when I move it back to it's original position. The code changes the size of the application frame and temporally  remove taskbar and user/time info pane at the top. It also doesn't seem to want to allow the use to touch the box that the minimize/exit/fullscreen buttons are in. It just hides everything and leave me with a blank screen.
The code works as follows: var app; creates new application frame(exit/fullscreen/minimize button + content). The width and height are defined by w and h in the functions first line which is called upon in my js file called front-end.js  by calling createFrame(500,300); . Content_src should explain itself quit easily although the parameter in not used yet. The fullscreen button should be able to work as stated above but for some reason int wont work properly if I drag it around on the screen. That is ok for now as I have not worked out code to re-position it to 0,0 on the screen. But if  I re-position it to 0,0 myself in the desktop it will not end up at 0,0 of the screen. I think this has something to do with me upsetting the position i.e. the application was not in draggable state till I moved it. Any ideas?

```
var isFullScreen;

function createFrame(w,h,content_src) {
    var app = $('<div class = "application-frame ui-resizable-se" style="width:'+w+'px; height:'+h+'px;">\
                    <div class = "buttons-box">\
                        <div class = "exit-button">\
                        </div>\
                        <div class = "fullscreen-button">\
                        </div>\
                        <div class = "minimise-button">\
                        </div>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class = "content">\
                    </div>\
                 </div>');  
    var apps = [];
    $(".desktop-box").append(app);
    apps.push(app);
    $(app).draggable({containment:"parent"}).resizable({containment:"parent",maxHeight: 678,maxWidth: 1361});

    $(".exit-button").click(function() {
        for(var i = 0; i <apps.length;i++) {
            apps[i].pop($(app).fadeOut('very slow'));
            for(var f = 0; f < fullscreenArray.length;f++) {
                if(fullscreenArray[f]) {
                    $(".infoPane").show();
                    $(".info-dropdown").show();
                    $(".taskbar").show();
                    fullscreenArray[f] = false;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    var fullscreenArray = [];
    fullscreenArray.push(isFullScreen);

    $(".minimisse-button").click(function() {
        for(var i = 0; i <apps.length;i++) {
            for(var f = 0; f < fullscreenArray.length;f++) {
                if(fullscreenArray[f]) {
                    $(".infoPane").show();
                    $(".info-dropdown").show();
                    $(".taskbar").show();
                    fullscreenArray[f] = false;
                    apps[i].pop($(app).slideToggle('very slow'));
                }
            }
        }
    });
    var fullScreenWidth = $(".desktop-box").width();
    var fullScreenHeight = $("body").height()+5;

    $(".fullscreen-button").click(function() {
        for(var f = 0; f < fullscreenArray.length;f++) {
            if(!fullscreenArray[f]) {
                $(app).css({width:fullScreenWidth});
                $(app).css({height:fullScreenHeight});
                fullscreenArray[f] = true;
                $(".infoPane").hide();
                $(".info-dropdown").hide();
                $(".taskbar").hide();
            }else if(fullscreenArray[f]) {
                $(app).css({width:w});
                $(app).css({height:h});
                fullscreenArray[f] = false;
                $(".application-frame").draggable();
                $(".infoPane").show();
                $(".info-dropdown").show();
                $(".taskbar").show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution to the problem if anybody else is trying to attempt something similar. All add is $(app).offset({top:0,left:0); in the if statement that makes isFullScreen true. and that will work!